# How to set datasource when tying oneself to Spring's HibernateDaoSupport

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have been reading that using `HibernateDaoSupport` isn't a good idea, so I need some help on how to NOT use it :)

Old code:

public class GenericDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport
        implements GenericDao {

```
    @Override
    public T get(Class<T> type, K id) {

        return super.getHibernateTemplate().get(type, id);
    }
```

}

My Dao now looks like:

```
public class GenericDaoImpl<T, K extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, K> {

    @Resource
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // @Override
    public T get(Class<T> type, K id) {

        return (T)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(type, id);
        //return super.getHibernateTemplate().get(type, id);
    }
}
```

My spring.xml is now having issues setting the datasource since the property doesn't exist in my `GenericDaoImpl`.

How do I set the datasource now?

```
    <bean id="userDao" class="com.agilely.platform.services.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

IntelliJ is complaining (and righly so) of the `dataSource` since there is no setter property.

How do I wireup the `dataSource` just like how the `HibernateDaoSupport` did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You supply the `DataSource` to the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`

Comment: meaning in the spring application-context.xml file sessionFactory bean?

Comment: but now I get org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread.  I guess the HibernateDaoSupport did that for me?

Comment: @Transactional also does it - it opens a session. Try it

Comment: I put @Transactional on both my controller and dao, didn't work.

Comment: and of course `<tx:annotation-driven />`. Read about transactions in the spring docs

Comment: what kind of trasactional scope did the HibernateDaoSupport do?  was it per db call?

Comment: I guess it started a transaction on-demand, if there wasn't one open

Comment: Yeah I want a very narrow transaction, I don't really care really so whatever is fastest at this point.  I'd rather start with very low scope and then work a solution if there is an issue.